# 2sxc: How to disable the quick insert hover items?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

For the 2sxc DNN module: Is it possible to disable the "quick insert" menu (with "add content module" and "add app module") that appears when I hover over ANY module or pane on the page...whether in Edit mode or not? See screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmS8f.jpg)

I only use the Content module in a few areas and DNN's core HTML module for the rest of the content. It's very confusing to my editors. They keep accidentally adding more Content modules to the page and it's just visually distracting if not needed/wanted. It would be nice to have a choice in whether this feature is enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no real switch to do this, but you can easily do it yourself.

There are some unique css classes. If you target them in your CSS, you can make it go away. I would need more time to figure out exactly which ones they are, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As @iJungleBoy recommended I did it with CSS using the [Snipped Inject App](http://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/snippet-inject-html-fragment-css-js-etc). Unfortunately this App also adds some menus i don't want. This is my CSS rule:

`.sc-content-block-menu, .DnnModule-7777 .sc-menu { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

These answers are old - you can now do it by adding an attribute to any dom-element as described here: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Html-Js-%24quickE